# Python: why can a variable stand on its own?

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner in python told my friend today, that the following code would throw an error, but it did not:

```
a = 5
a
```

So I wondered, what does "a" actually do and why is the interpreter fine with this?

If this is a duplicate, please refer me to the right post and sorry in advance.

**edit**: I used a *.py file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type this code into the shell and click enter, the value of a is returned. Functionally, as there is no operation being performed on a, the value of a will not change.

You define the variable in the line above. The variable contains a value, so the "NameError: name 'a' is not defined" error is not triggered.

[image: a=5]

Also, even if the variable is a different data type, for example, a string, the value of a is returned. [image: a="hello"]

If you run the code in a different environment, the line won't be printed and the line won't impact the value of itself or of any other variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you tried it in der REPL Console, paste it to a *.py file and execute that. So when you just type the variable name and hit enter this is actually a print command behind the scenes

Comment: It's not accurate to say it's a print command behind the scenes. While it will be displayed on the console when running interactively, that doesn't make it a print statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can type in a int into the shell or whatever, and it will return it. The variable you put is just a int, so it returns `5`.